# Getting "Too many requests" while opening Stack Overflow page

Tags: support, error-message, rate-limiting

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask this question.

I am getting "**Too many requests**" while  opening stackoverflow page, it may be less frequent but it is happening. First I thought it is happening for me only but later on I checked with other developers working with me and found out that they are also getting the same error.

I am using stackoverflow for more than 2 years and I am observing this issue from past 1 month.

How this can be resolved? I know this issue solves automatically after sometime but I don't have that much time to wait :-(.

[image]

Comment: Are you sharing a single (externally facing) IP address with all of these people?

Comment: [It is "Stack Overflow", not "stackoverflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit your question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same. I noticed that Safari (OSX) is creating a ton of requests when going here. When i use Chrome it seems fine. I mailed the team. Are you using Safari as-well? (btw im just alone on a network, with one page to SO and no scripts running). When you run in the terminal [watch "netstat -an | grep 151.101."] you can see the connections being created...

Answer (score 5):

Do as it says. Contact the team at team@stackexchange.com and include the listed information.

We cannot help you with this.

Comment: Maybe we add make that text in the <blink> tags. It isn't easily readable (for some atleast)

Comment: It looks like our normal rate throttling on the load balancers - if a lot of traffic comes from one IP in a short time, that's what one would see (you can refresh a page multiple times or open a bunch of questions in different tabs to get the throttle) - the throttle clears within a couple of minutes. And it effects *anyone* who causes it - employees and developers included.

Comment: I regularly keep 10–20 tabs of SO questions open, sometimes more, and I've never seen this throttling, even when re-opening my browser, which reloads all the saved tabs at once!